# Try to develop Chrome Extension for freely changing UserAgent, but it doesn't work well

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, user-agent, webrequest, chrome-webrequest

I am developting chrome-extension.

I want to change UserAgent of browser with rewriting http header using chrome-webrequest API, but something is wrong...

I want this codes to behave expected, but I don't know what to do.

Can I give me advices??

****BrowserConfig.js****

```js
class BrowserConfig {
  apply (userAgent, language) {
  let targetURL = "<all_urls>"
  function rewriteHeader(e) {
    e.requestHeaders.forEach(function(header){
      let headerName = header.name.toLowerCase();
      if (headerName === "user-agent") {
        header.value = userAgent;
      }
    });
    return {requestHeaders: e.requestHeaders};
  }
    
  chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    rewriteHeader,
    {urls: [targetURL]},
    ["blocking", "requestHeaders", "extraHeaders"]
  );
}
```

****background.js****

```js
import BrowserConfig from 'pass/to/BrowserConfig.js'
const browserConfig = new BrowserConfig()

// browserOptions example...  {userAgent: HeadlessChrome}
chrome.storage.local.get('browserOptions', ({ browserOptions }) => {
    this.browserConfig.apply(browserOptions.userAgent)
})
```

***Expected Behavior***

Every time set browserOption, UserAgent change to desired

ex.)

**1st**:
browserOption = {userAgent: HeadlessBrowser}
=> userAgent: HeadlessBrowser

**2nd**:
browserOption = {userAgent: aaaaaa}
=> userAgent: aaaaaa

***Actual Behavior***

Only once, I can change UserAgent to desired.
But, from the second time, I cannot change it.

ex.)

**1st**:
browserOption = {userAgent: HeadlessBrowser}
=> userAgent: HeadlessBrowser

**2nd~**:
browserOption = {userAgent: aaaaaa}
=> userAgent: HeadlessBrowser

Comment: Use chrome.storage.onChanged event. You'll have to rewrite your BrowserConfig to allow changing the data. For example apply() and rewriteHeader() can set/get userAgent in `this`, instead of using the parameter directly, which will allow you to expose an additional method like reconfigure(newData).